# Express only creating objectID without data in it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to create a survey object by calling post curl request. I got response back, but there are some data is missing (but _id is populating) and I don't know where is the problem. Please help.

```
const surveySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      title: {
        type: String,
      },
      questions: [
        [{ query: { type: String}},
         {option: { type: String }, numberOfVotes: { type: Number, default: 0 } }]
      ]},
      {
        timestamps: true,
      });
```

above is my schema, and below is the response I got from response, which missed option & numberOfVotes field. I checked req.body, I send all the req, but we translate to res, it only generate id for me without actual field and data.

```
questions: [[{query: "meow?",_id: "57859439f7ef416550e0aa17"},
    {_id: "57859439f7ef416550e0aa16"},
    {_id: "57859439f7ef416550e0aa15"}
]]
```

And create function is like below:

```
const create = (req, res, next) => {
  let survey = Object.assign(
    req.body.survey,
    {
    _owner: req.currentUser._id
  });
  Survey.create(survey)
  .then(survey => res.json({ survey }))
  .catch(err => next(err));
};
```

Comment: Have you tried doing `console.log(req.body.survey);`? What is printed out to the console? There is a chance that the problem is on the client. I'm guessing that your Mongoose schema probably doesn't align with what is contained in 'req.body.survey'. Either that or those fields are empty. Its usually good idea to do some kind of processing before saving a new document to the db. Using the instance 'save' method will force you to do this.

Comment: In "questions" array you have in fact 2 objects, but in response 3 ids were returned. Thereby, i presume that your cURL request has incorrect structure. It has to be identical with schema (all arrays and objects)

Comment: Sorry for missing clarification. I passed 2 option,numberOfVotes object for my curl request.```-data '{
  "survey": {
    "title": "example for new schema",
    "questions": [
    [{"query": "meow?"}, {"option": "please", "numberOfVotes": 2}, {"option": "work", "numberOfVotes": 3}]
    ]
  }
}```So you can see 3 id there

Comment: I checked for req.body.survey.questions, below is what I got ``` [ [ { query: 'meow?' },
    { option: 'please', numberOfVotes: 2 },
    { option: 'work', numberOfVotes: 3 } ],
  [ { query: 'testing?' },
    { option: 'load', numberOfVotes: 1 },
    { option: 'cmaaan', numberOfVotes: 3 } ] ]``` So the request body is passing the correct data.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help.